# Автоматическое обновление Widget

Tags: android, android-studio

Я сделала простой виджет по урокам, обычное прозрачное окно и в центре пока только текст. Хочу, чтоб каждую минуту текст менялся сам, я не знаю как взаимодействовать с ним. Мне не нужно, менять вручную, просто чтоб он сам менялся например раз в 5 минут. Как это сделать?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"> 
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/tvTxt" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="#41434242" 
android:gravity="center" 
android:text="@string/widget_text" 
android:textColor="#161515" 
android:textSize="20sp"> 
</TextView> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Посмотрите тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how

Comment: что именно не получается? Поменять текст? Или выполнять код через промежуток времени?

Comment: я знаю как поменять текст через определенной промежуток времени, но не знаю как сделать это в виджете. Я сейчас читаю, думаю нужно использовать сервис, но как это сделать и правильно ли это?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно реализовать данное несколькими способами, но для экономии аккумулятора лучше ставить интервал побольше. Ну а так как минимальный стандартный интервал для виджета 30 минут, а необходимо меньше, вот некоторые способы:
3. `Service` - запускаете сервис, который будет через определенное время обновлять виджет.2. `Handler` -  используйте .postDelayed и указывайте заданный интервал. Ну и наилучший способ:
1. `AlarmManager` - так сказать, обновления по будильнику:

В `onEnabled` виджета:

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000*60*5 , pendingIntent);
```

Создаете получатель:

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "TAG");
        wakeLock.acquire();

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.yours_widget_layout);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.your_textView, "Text for widget");
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, YourWidgetClass.class);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
        wakeLock.release();
    }
}
```

Ну и в `onDisabled` виджета останавливаем:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

P.S. не забудьте в манифесте прописать разрешения `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` и получателя.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а AlarmManager не будет включать подсветку или телефон при срабатывании? По сути это и есть service только стандартный? Я как только разберусь с кодом, отвечу, ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, он абсолютно решает вопрос, просто я наверное не правильно спросила. Я задам другой вопрос, буду благодарна ответам.

Comment: Ну у меня не изменился текст  на Text for widget